# SQL Query for counting the number of days a particular balance of an account is continuing

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Lets say I have an account balance table with the following information for a particular account 'X':

```
Date             Balance  
01/01/2016       100   
02/01/2016       100  
03/01/2016       100   
04/01/2016       200  
05/01/2016       200  
06/01/2016       100  
07/01/2016       100  
08/01/2016       500  
09/01/2016       100  
10/01/2016       600
```

I need output like below:

```
FromDate    UptoDate      Balance      NoOfDays  
01/01/2016  03/01/2016    100          3  
04/01/2016  05/01/2016    200          2  
06/01/2016  07/01/2016    100          2  
08/01/2016  08/01/2016    500          1  
09/01/2016  09/01/2016    100          1  
10/01/2016  10/01/2016    600          1
```

The above dates are given in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format and I am using Oracle11gR2.

Answer (score 2):

A common solution to this problem is based on two sequences:

```
select account, min(date), max(date), balance, count(*)
from
 (
   select 
      account, date, balance,
      -- assigns a meaningless number to each row 
      -- same number as long as the balance doesn't change
      row_number() over (partition by account order by date) -
      row_number() over (partition by account, balance order by date) as grp
   from account_balane
 ) dt
group by account, balance, grp
```

Comment: Partition by Balance is a wrong idea I guess, because if you look into the sample data, you can not say that 100 amount continued for min(Date): 01/01/2016 - max(Date): 07/01/2016 = 7 days, rather it continued for 5 days in total intermittently.

Comment: @raatprohory: It's working as expected, simply try it.

Comment: I don't think its working perfectly though it may have worked for the sample data that I had posted earlier. Now that I have tweaked the data (and the output also), do you think your query is going to work? For example, the 4th (200), 5th (200) and 9th (100) rows of the sample data above can have the same "grp" value "3" assigned which can give incorrect result as they are for different amounts.

Comment: @raatprohory: They may get the same `grp` value, but those rows got different `balance`. You should get an error message when you try to run my query as-is, I forgot to add `balance` to `GROUP BY`.